# How to publish an endless JSON stream as a REST service in Java Enterprise 7

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, stream

I would like to ask for an example to publish a **JSON endless stream** through a REST service with Java EE but I can't find an example or tutorial.

Let's say I need to send a continuous serie of instances of an New object:

```
public class New {
    public String title;
    public String content;
}
```

How is it possible?

Comment: You plan to keep the HTTP connection alive forever?

Comment: I suppose this is how social networks like Twitter and FB do.
But I am open to other solutions too.

Comment: No, that's not how they do it. There are protocols that have been developed specifically to accomodate pseudo-async messaging between disconnected entities. You should state your concrete use case. There are options like [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) or Websockets